# Safari doesn't correctly change active element on focus

Tags: javascript, html, safari, focus

I have a tooltip which depends on becoming the active element when clicked, so that on blur it can hide.

In a decent browser like Chrome a `<button>` becomes the active element when clicked. In FF and Safari it doesn't (they don't even call `focus` on the element!).

So I switched to an `<a>`, but even that is still broken in Safari.

Here is a demo of the issue, try in Chrome and then Safari:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
  echoActiveEl();
});

function echoActiveEl() {
  document.querySelector('.active-el-tag').innerHTML = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
}

echoActiveEl();
```

```html
<a href="#blah">Click me</a>

<p>Active element: <span class="active-el-tag"></span></p>
```

How can I make Safari behave properly and call `focus` on the element so it becomes the activeElement? Doing `element.focus()` does nothing! Thanks.

**Edit:** `e.currentTarget.focus()` does actually work, `e.target` was pointing to a `span` I had in my `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as manually putting focus is concerned i think it's an ES 6 support issue , try traditional syntax instead

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  //e.preventDefault();
  this.focus();
  document.querySelector('.active-el-tag').innerHTML = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();

});
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I had tried e.currentTarget, but this led me back to it as `this` points to `e.currentTarget` and either work (also in an arrow func)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the `onBlur` event, you can archive what you want with something like this:

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('blur', () => {
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    echoBluredEl(targetElement)
});

function echoBluredEl(ele) {
   document.querySelector('.blured-el-tag').innerHTML = ele.tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```